# UIButton autoresizing woes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton, autoresizingmask

Trying to get UIButtons to decrease height but maintain width when device is rotated.
Here's code from `initWithFrame:` of the view that contains the buttons.

ParentView.m

```
self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, UIKeyboardPortraitHeightPhone, 320)];
self.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
self.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

// And then on each button I call
myButton.frame = myFrame;
myButton.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin);
```

**The problem**: Before I even rotate the device, the buttons have resized and gotten smaller (in height) than the frame I initialized them to.

**Previous research**: It looks like I'm having the same problem as this person: [Cannot get UIButton autoresizingMask to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673008/cannot-get-uibutton-autoresizingmask-to-work), but I followed the advice and got the same unsatisfactory result.

I also looked at the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AdoptingaFull-ScreenLayout/AdoptingaFull-ScreenLayout.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH13-SW1), which say that the autoresizing mask is only supposed to take effect when the bounds of the parent view change. Obviously either the bounds of my parent view are changing without me realizing it, or something else fishy is going on here.

Any ideas as to what could be the problem?

Comment: have you checked `initWithFrame:` is called with correct (final) frame size?

Comment: Yeah, the parent view's fame is actually hardcoded in, just added that now. To clarify though, the parent view is resizing fine. It's the buttons that are inexplicably shrinking in height.

Comment: are you using Storyboards with your ViewController?